# Why is a query slow on a table with millions of records in oracle despite no change in it?

Tags: oracle, query-performance

This question is most commonly asked in job interviews but i could not find the perfect answer for it.

Why is it that a table(small or big) has queries run fast on it initially, but later on queries become slow.  There have been no changes made to the table.
What could be the reason?

Comment: There could be many reasons, what do you mean by **no changes made to the table**? And how do you differentiate between a **small table** and **big table**? Millions of rows is not a measure of how big a table is.

Comment: This is an interesting question but not a good fit for this site. A question this theoretical has no clear answer, and will require a never-ending list of ideas.

Comment: The question was asked in oracle sql interview, and it was framed exactly this way making me more confused. They said for any table, the query initially fast becomes slow. What could be the reason behind it.

Comment: by no changes mean, no indexes altered, no new rows inserted/deleted/updated